# Integration by Parts for multivariable functions

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let also $f$ be twice continuously differentiable, $f \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$,
and the function $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f(x_1,x_2)$ be absolutely integrable,
$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f(x_1,x_2)\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

I am wondering what are sufficient conditions for the following identity to hold
\begin{align*}
  &\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2} f(x_1,x_2)  dx_1dx_2\\
  &\qquad\qquad=
  \left(f(x_1,x_2)\Big\vert_{x_1=-\infty}^{x_1=+\infty} \right)\Big\vert_{x_2=-\infty}^{x_2=+\infty}\\
   &\qquad\qquad= 
  f(+\infty,+\infty) - f(+\infty,-\infty) -  f(-\infty,+\infty) + f(-\infty,-\infty)?
\end{align*}

I would appreciate any ideas, suggestions, counterexamples. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first resolve the ambiguity of notation such as $f(+\infty, +\infty)$. This could mean the double limit $\lim_{x,y \to +\infty}f(x,y)$, either of the iterated limits $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \lim_{y \to +\infty} f(x,y)$, a symmetric limit $\lim_{x \to +\infty} f(x,x)$, etc.  For functions in general, some, all or none of these limits may exist.  If all exist then they may not be equal.

As will be shown in this case, all such limits will exist and we can without bias select an iterated limit as the definition.

You have already given sufficient conditions by stating that the mixed second partial derivative exists everywhere and is absolutely integrable.

Absolute integrability and Fubini's theorem stipulates the integral over any rectangle $[a,b] \times [c,d]$ can be taken as iterated integrals in any order and there exists an upper bound $M$ such that

$$\int_c^d \left(  \int_a^b\left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} \right| \, dx_1 \right)\, dx_2  \leqslant M. $$

By dominated convergence, the integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ exists as a limit (in any order)

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(  \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}  \, dx_1 \right)\, dx_2  = \lim_{b,d \to +\infty,a,c \to -\infty} \int_c^d \left(  \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}  \, dx_1 \right)\, dx_2.$$

Since $f \in C^2$ the first partial derivatives are continuous and integrable, and since the mixed second partial derivative is integrable we can apply the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC) to obtain

$$  \int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}  \, dx_1 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(b,x_2) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(a,x_2).$$

Integrating and applying the FTC again over $[c,d]$ we obtain

$$  \int_c^d \left(\int_a^b\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}  \, dx_1 \right) \, dx_2= f(b,d) - f(b,c) - f(a,d) + f(a,c).$$

It is then valid to take the limit of both sides as $b,d \to +\infty$ and $a,c \to -\infty$ in any order to obtain the final result.

Comment: RRL, thank you very much for the answer. Could you please comment on the dominated convergence theorem? Am I right that we take
$g_{a,b,c,d}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} f(x_1,x_2) \cdot I\{x_1 \in [a,b], x_2 \in [c,d]\}$
and
$
g(x_1,x_2) = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_1 \partial x_2} f(x_1,x_2).
$

So, $|g_{a,b,c,d}(x_1,x_2)| \leq |g(x_1,x_2)| \in L_1$ and 
the Integral over $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $g_{a,b,c,d}(x_1,x_2)$ converges to the integral of $g(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: @user44097: That argument is essentially correct.  The sense  of convergence would need to be made precise.  We could proceed a number of ways depending how we define the integral -- Lebesgue or improper Riemann.  As the latter, we could define the improper integral as the limit of any sequence of integrals over compact rectangles $D_n$ where $D_n \subset D_{n+1}$ and $\cup_n D_n = \mathbb{R}^2$.  This definition will only be useful with absolute convergence -- which we have here. In the case of conditional convergence, a unique limit may not exists under that definition.

Comment: For an example of difficulties with conditional convergence see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2138689/148510). See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2355095/148510) on the relationship between the Lebesgue and improper Riemann integral.

Comment: Thanks! I am right that this statement can be generalized to the dimension more than 2, i.e. from $f\in C^{d}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\ldots\frac{\partial}{\partial x_d} f(x_1,\ldots, x_n) \in L_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$ follows integration by parts as written above?

Comment: You're welcome. It should generalize as you say.